# Confused between the usage of constructors and what to/what not to place in them.

Tags: c++, constructor

I had basics in C, and I've just started programming in c++ two weeks ago, and find 'classes' confusing. My question is how do i put a 'cin' to input the value to determine marks, and also how do i print the grades based on the below code? I'm only printing A to F and i'm so blur right now. And for some reason if i put 'else if' instead of just 'if' the error reads as missing ; before cout. Have way too many questions, sorry about that..

```
#include <iostream>   
using namespace std;

class StudentMark {
private:
float mark;

public:
StudentMark() //constructor
{
mark = 0.0;
cout << "Constructed an instance of class StudentMark\n";
}

void SetMark(float markofstudent)
{
mark = markofstudent;
}

void IntroduceMark()
{

if (80<mark<100)
cout << "A" << endl;

if (65<mark<79)
cout << "B" << endl;

if (50<mark<64)
cout << "C" << endl;

if (40<mark<49)
cout << "D" << endl;

if (0<mark<39)
cout << "F" << endl;
}
};

int main()
{
StudentMark FirstStudent;

FirstStudent.SetMark(89);

FirstStudent.IntroduceMark();
}
```

Comment: `if (80<mark<100)` is wrong. Use `if (80 < mark && mark < 100)`

Comment: Read the input separately, don't do it in the constructor. The constructor is only to initialize the object, if you want to initialize a member variable to a specific value create a constructor which takes the value as an argument.

Comment: Even if you fix it as suggested, it will still output nothing for a mark of 0, 39, 40, 49, 50, 64, 65, 79, 80, or 100.

Answer (score 1):

Read about "Separation of concerns" - in this case, you're defining a class `StudentMark` which represents instances of a course grade. Therefore the class `StudentMark` should only be concerned with the score itself - it should not be concerned with program input and output - because (for example) what if you wanted to reuse your `StudentMark` class in a platform that didn't have a text-mode console, such as a web-application or console video game? So the responsibility of using `cin` and `cout` lies elsewhere.

Similarly the constructor of your `StudentMark` type should be concerned only with initializing a `StudentMark` instance. In your case you're simply zeroing-out the `score` member - you don't need an explicit constructor for this.

Finally, your `IntroduceMark` method looks like it's concerned with converting the numerical score to a grade-letter. That's all it should do - it should not be concerned with outputting it to the user of your program. I think `getGrade` is a better name that is more descriptive of its purpose.

```
class StudentMark {
private:
    float mark = 0;
public:
    void setMark(float mark);
    char getGrade();
}

void StudentMark::setMark(float mark) {
    this->mark = mark;
}

char StudentMark::getGrade() {
    if( this->mark < 39 ) return 'F';
    if( this->mark < 49 ) return 'E';
    if( this->mark < 59 ) return 'D';
    if( this->mark < 69 ) return 'C';
    // etc
}
```

And then used like so:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    StudentMark mark;
    cout << "Instantiated a StudentMark" << endl;
    mark.setMark( 70 );
    cout << mark.getGrade() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are only used as a method of creating/initializing anything that's necessary for the class to function when an object of that class is created for the first time.

They're also used as means to provide default/user-input values to the class's variables.
They should be only run once when an object of the class is instantiated.

You should think of them as the "loading" process of your class.
Constructors are especially useful when working with databases for example, for the constructor is where the connection to the database happens, which is *necessary* if you wanted to manipulate the database using member functions.

#### What to put in constructors:

In general, anything that the class *requires* for it's member functions to function, including variables that weren't assigned values in previous code.

#### What not to put in constructors:

Practically anything else that isn't required for the class to function properly.

Here's an illustration of how constructors work.

```
class StudentMark {
public:
    //Create variable m_mark, it hasn't been assigned a value,
    // therefore contains junk for a value.
    float m_mark;

    //The constructor is called when an object of this class is created.
    //Giving mark a default value of 0.0.
    StudentMark(float mark = 0.0)
    {
        //m_mark contained junk, now it contains the value mark.
        m_mark = mark;
    }
}

int main()
{
    //firstMark is instantiated, it's constructor gets called.
    //Since we didn't provide any user input, the default value
    //which is 0.0 gets assigned to firstMark.m_mark.
    StudentMark firstMark;

    //Now when secondMark is instantiated, it is provided with
    //the value 80, therefore m_mark gets assigned the value 80.
    StudentMark secondMark(80);
}
```

Finally, [Learncpp](http://www.learncpp.com/) has very informative tutorials on classes aswell as many other aspects of the language, I strongly recommend you give them a read.